# adding fake foders to using with apache mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I want to rewrite

```
http://site.tld/fake1/fake2/page?options
```

to

```
http://site.tld/page?options
```

basically getting everything is after the last slash, so without knowing in advance any fake foder names

Comment: Despite the fact that your question is too broad, this is also a terrible idea because it would lead to duplicate content, which is, in term of seo, really bad

Comment: tnx @JustinIurman for pointing it out, but since i'm goint to create links to the page without duplication (pear.php will always linked as fruits/pear.php) how can a search engine can invent other links ? I belive I can also fix this using meta canonical url ..

Comment: So be it. You can see my answer about it

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups and replace as follows.

**Regex:** `^(.*\.tld\/).*?([^\/]*$)$`

**Explanation:**

- `^(.*\.tld\/)` matches beginning part till domain name.
- `.*?` matches the `fake1/fake2/`
- `([^\/]*$)$` matches the later part of URL.

**Replacement to do:** Replace with back-referencing groups `\1\2`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xP4xJ6/1)**

Comment: regex is ok, but cannot make it work inside mod-rewrite: rule is not met (I also checked with [link](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), do you have any hint ? You also managed the domain, but being inside a virtual host it would not be necessary, or you needed some anchor to work within the regex?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you've enabled *mod_rewrite* and allowed *htaccess* in Apache configuration file.

Then, put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+?/([^/]+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```